# GDI+ round corner image c++

Tags: c++, graphics, mfc, gdi

I'm using GDI+ to draw image on a `CStatic *element` using this class :
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24969/An-MFC-picture-control-to-dynamically-show-picture

Here is my code `onDraw`

```
void CPictureCtrl::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
{
if (mBIsPicLoaded)  {
    RECT rc;
    this->GetClientRect(&rc);

    Graphics graphics(lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);
    Image image(mPstream);
    graphics.DrawImage(&image, (INT)rc.left, (INT)rc.top, (INT)(rc.right - rc.left), (INT)(rc.bottom - rc.top));
}
}
```

The image is displayed as a rectangle. But I would like to make it round.
How to do it ?
Thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535824(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you I did not notice this function.
Is it possible to extract the buffer of Image from the graphic?